# Finding the middle of a parallelogram

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a label, therefor I need to find the center of a parallelogram, this is my code but it is definitely not centered.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0uoprmj/)

```css
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  width: 82px;
  height: 32px;
  position: relative;
}

.paralellogram {
  width: 82px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
  border: 1px solid #17B3E6;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

.line {
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="paralellogram"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

It's not the only thing doing weird stuff, the parallelogram also doesnt fit its wrapper because of skew.

Comment: are you trying to style a label with a shape of that kind https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zdPzwg ? if yes, just let the parent grow to the size label needs to be ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the line looks centralized for me. But I made a workaroung using the `transform` propertie:

```
 .line{
    width:3px;
    height:100%;
    background:purple;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    transform: translateX(39.5px); //(82px -3px)/2
 }
```

Comment: the line is centralized, but I want it to be in the middle of the top of the parallelogram

Answer (score 0):

The top side is shifted to the right by `0.5*height*sin(skewDeg)/sin(90-skewDeg)` (`0.5` because the bottom is shifted to the left). In your case, `height = 32px` and `skewDeg = 20deg`, so the shift equals to `6px`.

Simply translate it an additional `6px` (and another 1.5 px to accomodate for the width of the line itself) to the right. For example, taking Yuri's answer and adding `7.5px` to it to get `translateX(47px)` and changing it to `left: 47px;` (because I see no reason to transform) should do the job.

**Edit:** To make the parallellogram completely contained in the wrapper, begin by shifting it `6px` to the right so it doesn't protrude from the left side of the wrapper. Then increase the width of the wrapper by `6px` for the original protrusion on the right side, then another `6px` since we just shifted it to the right, and finally another `2px` for the borders.

You also need to increase the height of the wrapper by `5px` because you have a margin of `3px` and two borders.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  width: 96px;
  height: 37px;
  position: relative;
}

.paralellogram {
  width: 82px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
  border: 1px solid #17B3E6;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
}

 .line{
    width:3px;
    height:100%;
    background:purple;
    position:absolute;
    left:53px;right:0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="paralellogram"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: anyway I could make the width and height of the wrapper wrap around the complete paralellogram?